# Como instalar pygame en Python3 con pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

¿Como puedo instalar pygame para python3 mediante pip?. Tengo la version de Python 3.6.3.

Probé con `pip install pygame` pero fue instalado en python 2.7.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dices que tienes python3, pero en cambio `pip` te lo ha instalado para python2, de donde se deduce que también tienes python2.

El mejor mencanismo para no montar un lío cuando tienes varias versiones de python instaladas en el sistema es usar un *entorno virtual*. En realidad, aunque el nombre intimida un poco, no es más que una carpeta con una versión concreta de python dentro de ella y en la que puedas instalar paquetes que no afecten al sistema ni a otras carpetas similares que hayas creado para otros proyectos o pruebas.

Los pasos son muy sencillos:

**Crear la carpeta (entorno virtual):**

```
$ python3 -m venv  ~/entornos/game
```

Esto ejecuta `python3` (así te aseguras de que el entorno virtual será para esta versión) y carga el módulo `venv`, el cual creará la carpeta `~/entornos/game` y meterá dentro varias carpetas con esa versión de python y sus librerías, así como una versión apropiada de `pip`. Puedes llamar como quieras a la carpeta, pero es buena costumbre crearlas todas en un mismo lugar para que te sea fácil encontrarlas. En este caso he supuesto que quieres crearlas todas dentro de la carpeta `entornos` de tu directorio raíz de usuario.

**Activar el entorno**

Mientras no actives el entorno, al usar desde línea de comandos `python` o `pip` se seguirán usando los de sistema. Para activarla debes poner:

```
$ source ~/entornos/game/bin/activate
```

Verás que tu *prompt* cambia y es ahora `(game) $`, como recordatorio de que has activado ese entorno virtual. Ahora cuando hagas `pip install`, se ejecutará el `pip` de ese entorno, y lo que instale lo hará dentro de esa carpeta, sin afectar al resto del sistema. Cuando ejecutes `python` se ejecutará el de esa carpeta y por tanto encontrará los paquetes allí instalados.

**Desactivar el entorno**

Cuando quieras volver a usar el python del sistema (por ejemplo, para crear otro entorno virtual), basta que escribas:

```
(game) $ deactivate
```

El *prompt* volverá a su forma normal para recordarte que ya no estás en el entorno virtual. El comando `python` volverá a ser el defecto del sistema (y no tendrás ya acceso a los paquetes que habías instalado mientras estabas en el entorno virtual).

El entorno también se abandona si cierras la terminal. Esto implica que cada vez que abras una terminal nueva para trabajar en ese entorno debes volver a activarlo como indiqué más arriba.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente lo soluciones con:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools

sudo easy_install3 pip

sudo pip3.6 install pygame
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707566/how-to-install-pygame-for-python3-5-in-ubuntu16-04

Comment: Te he dado una respuesta en la que sugiero que uses entornos virtuales, que son mucho más adecuados para experimentos

Answer (score 1):

Para instalar pygame, sigue estos pasos:

1. En el comando de Windows (CMD), enfoca la dirección que contiene la carpeta Scripts, debería estar en el mismo directorio donde tenes instalado el python.exe.  En mi caso: `C:\Users\Fran\Python\Scripts`

En CMD, sería:  `cd C:\Users\Fran\Python\Scripts`

2. Luego, utiliza el comando pip install, y listo: `pip install Pygame`

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pues en su pregunta el comparte que ya hizo ese comando y que no le resultó

Comment: Pero no aclara que localizo la carpeta Scripts. Si probas con el comando que menciona, sin ubicar la carpeta, no te dejará instalar el módulo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Espero te resulte

Answer (score 0):

no se ustedes pero casi muero en el intento entonces puse pip install Pygame  con la  p en mayuscula y de proto todo se ilumino jalo de maravilla

cuando le di pip list alli estaba, no se por que en pycharm lo pide con minusculas por completo y nunca lo instala

Answer (score 0):

Pueden probar con:

```
pip3 install Pygame
```

Si no se descarga la ultima versión, con el siguiente comando pueden Actualizar:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Esto fue hecho en Windows 10. es muy importante que estén realizando esto dentro del usuario donde esta instalado Python.

[image: Comandos para instalar Pygame en Windows 10]